# How to execute console command from the controller in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have developed a CLI command in Zend Framework 2. I want to run it from the controller. How can I do this in Zend Framework 2?

Comment: Have you defined any console routes?Add them. What is your Controller and action name? Do you pass any parameters to your action?

Answer (score 0):

You should forward your request to the specific CLI ConsoleController you have in mind. You can achieve this by using the `Forward` plugin. For example:

```
class HttpController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // do some stuff
        $response = $this->forward()->dispatch(ConsoleController::class, ['action' => 'process']);
        // do stuff with your response | array
        $bar = $response['foo'];
    }

}

class ConsoleController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function processAction()
    {
        // do stuff
        return ['foo' => 'bar'];
    }

}
```

Note that I call `ConsoleController::class` within the first argument. You should match the way how your controllers are registred within your configuration.

```
return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            HttpController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            ConsoleController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
        'aliases' => [
            'ConsoleController' => ConsoleController::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Note that calling `$this->forward()->dispatch('ConsoleController', ['action' => 'process'])` is also a valid option, as the Dispatch looks for registered controllers.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this:

```
$cmd = "php filenameToRun.php";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

or like this:

```
$cmd = "pwd";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

or like this:

```
$cmd = "mkdir myNewFolder";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Any regular command you put into brackets will work.

Comment: English is my first language, so I could correct it by myself